# How to get Unique Key of childs in firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, arraylist

i am new to Firebase
so i have a scenario where i have to set a check that if a hotel is already present in FavouriteHotels Node, then this must Toast that this hotel is already present in FavouriteHotels Node else Just Store that clicked hotel. like in this code.

```
final String favHotel_Id = myRef.push().getKey();
                            myRef.child("Users").child(mUser.getUid())
                                    .addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                                            for (DataSnapshot userSnapshot : snapshot.getChildren()) {
                                                if (!userSnapshot.child("FavouriteHotels").exists()){
                                                    Log.d(TAG, "onDataChange: "+userSnapshot.getChildren());
                                                    if (Objects.equals(hotelArrayList.get(position).getHotelName(), userSnapshot.child("Name").getValue() )) {
                                                        Toast.makeText(mContext, "Already saved to favourite hotels", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                                    } else {
                                                        if (favHotel_Id != null) {
                                                            myRef.child("Users").child(mUser.getUid()).child("FavouriteHotels").child(favHotel_Id).child("Name").setValue(hotelArrayList.get(position).getHotelName());
                                                            myRef.child("Users").child(mUser.getUid()).child("FavouriteHotels").child(favHotel_Id).child("Image").setValue(hotelArrayList.get(position).getImageID());
                                                            myRef.child("Users").child(mUser.getUid()).child("FavouriteHotels").child(favHotel_Id).child("rating").setValue(hotelArrayList.get(position).getHotelRating());
                                                            myRef.child("Users").child(mUser.getUid()).child("FavouriteHotels").child(favHotel_Id).child("Price").setValue(hotelArrayList.get(position).getHotelPrice());
                                                        }
                                                    }
                                                }else {
                                                    Toast.makeText(mContext, "No Data Found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                                }
                                            }
                                        }

                                        @Override
                                        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

                                        }
                                    });
```

one thing i want to mention is, i am saving this hotel item with its properties from ArrayList where i am getting that

```
if (Objects.equals(hotelArrayList.get(position).getHotelName(), userSnapshot.child("Name").getValue() )) {
                                                        Toast.makeText(mContext, "Already saved to favourite hotels", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                                    } else {
                                                        if (favHotel_Id != null) {
                                                            myRef.child("Users").child(mUser.getUid()).child("FavouriteHotels").child(favHotel_Id).child("Name").setValue(hotelArrayList.get(position).getHotelName());
                                                            myRef.child("Users").child(mUser.getUid()).child("FavouriteHotels").child(favHotel_Id).child("Image").setValue(hotelArrayList.get(position).getImageID());
                                                            myRef.child("Users").child(mUser.getUid()).child("FavouriteHotels").child(favHotel_Id).child("rating").setValue(hotelArrayList.get(position).getHotelRating());
                                                            myRef.child("Users").child(mUser.getUid()).child("FavouriteHotels").child(favHotel_Id).child("Price").setValue(hotelArrayList.get(position).getHotelPrice());
                                                        }
                                                    }
```

i want to fetch the unique Key of hotel highlighted in circle and putting a check on the Name of hotel that if `hotelArrayList.get(position).getHotelName(), userSnapshot.child("Name").getValue()`  then show me a toast that this hotel is already present in the db.

[image: This is my Firebase Database]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can get the push key like this.

```
Query query = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("your node path");
 query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
   @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    for (DataSnapshot snapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
        String key = snapshot.getKey();
        Log.i(TAG,key);
    }
}
```